# What does mean the "[XX000] ERROR: failed to build any 3-way joins" Postgresql error?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a JSONB field containing nested arrays.
I would like to explode the data in those nested JSON arrays to multiple rows while keeping the information about the place of each value in the arrays structure.

I have some queries which work until a certain level of nesting but i came to a point where Postgres fails with a `[XX000] ERROR: failed to build any 3-way joins` that I don't understand.

**Is anybody able to indicate what I am doing wrong and/or what is this error meaning?**

---

For convenience below is everything to reproduce the problem:

A very simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE random_table (
    random_field JSONB
);
```

A very nested JSONB data:

```
INSERT INTO public.random_table (random_field) VALUES ('{"bar": [[[1, 2, 3, 4]]], "foo": [[["abc", "def"], ["tuw", "xyz"]]]}');
```

A quite complex query:

```
SELECT *
FROM random_table
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT *
        FROM jsonb_array_elements(random_table.random_field -> 'foo')
            WITH ORDINALITY AS foo_level_1(foo_1, foo_1_index)
        LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
            SELECT *
            FROM jsonb_array_elements(foo_1)
                WITH ORDINALITY AS foo_level_2(foo_2, foo_2_index)
--             LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
--                 SELECT *
--                 FROM jsonb_array_elements(foo_2)
--                     WITH ORDINALITY AS foo_level_3(foo_3, foo_3_index)
--             ) AS foo_lateral_2 ON TRUE
        ) AS foo_lateral_1 ON TRUE

--         FULL OUTER JOIN jsonb_array_elements(random_table.random_field -> 'bar')
--             WITH ORDINALITY AS bar_level_1(bar_1, bar_1_index) ON FALSE
--         LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
--             SELECT *
--             FROM jsonb_array_elements(bar_1)
--                 WITH ORDINALITY AS bar_level_2(bar_2, bar_2_index)
--         ) AS bar_lateral_1 ON TRUE
    ) AS pouet ON TRUE;
```

Note the two commented parts:

- If the first one OR the second one is uncommented, the query seems to be working as expected (not finished but encouraging)
- If both are uncommented, The `[XX000] ERROR: failed to build any 3-way joins` occurs

[see the fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=46bd025d9270ae34db175b741bd2180f)

Obviously I would like to be able to uncomment the two commented parts and even complexify the FROM clause.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occured because of [a bug](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/19731.1554754422%40sss.pgh.pa.us) which is fixed in all PostgreSQL versions [released on 9th May 2019](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1939/).

This means all versions listed below (and hopefully the following) are OK:

- 9.4.22
- 9.5.17
- 9.6.13
- 10.8
- 11.3

Comment: This is why I love the Postgres community. Bug acknowledged 45 minutes after being reported and fixed 6 hours later.